# i want to take number from user then print if it prime or not but i can't find what is error where result always not prime so what is problem?

Tags: c, primes

i want to take number from user then print if it prime or not but i can't find what is error where result always not prime so what is problem??

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

    int number;
    char flag = 0;

    printf("Please enter the number:");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) { 
        if (number %i == 0) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (number==1)
        printf("%d neither prime nor not prime", number);

    if (flag==1)
        printf("%d is not prime",number);
    else
        printf("%d is prime",number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand and elaborate on the problem you the with the code you show? With some specific input, what is the actual output? What is the expected output? Also please take some time to read about [ask] good questions.

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code. Readability of your code is most important.

Comment: Lastly, this seems like a very good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: regarding: `for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)`   The smallest prime number is 2,  NOT 1

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding:  1) please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: Please note:  "a prime number is a 'natural' number that can only be evenly divided by 1 and itself."  This means 1 and below are not prime

Comment: Please get some C style formatting guidelines from the network and learn the common ways most professionals and serious students of programming format C code. Yours is hard to read. By following conventions it makes it easier for everyone to read and understand and help you fix code. Badly formatted code often leads to hard to find problems anyway. Keep your code need and consistent. I'll edit it for you this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edit to work successfully

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

int number ;
char flag=0;
printf("please enter the number:");
scanf("%d",&number);

for(int i=2;i<number;i++)
{ 
   if(number%i==0)
   {
     flag=1;
     break;
    }
}

if (number==1)
      { printf("%d neither prime nor not prime", number);}
else if (flag==1)
     { printf("%d is not prime",number);}
else
      { printf("%d is prime",number);}

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the loop condition here:

```
for(int i=1;i<=number;i++)
```

With `<=`, `i` goes up to `number`. So the last check will be `if(number%number==0)`, which is always true: your program says that `5` is not a prime number because `5` divided by `5` has remainder `0`. The same applies to dividing the number by `1` (which also results in no remainder), so this check should start at `2`. This line should be:

```
for(int i=2;i<number;i++)
```

Typically `i` only has to go up to `sqrt(number)` because no two numbers bigger than the root of `number` multiplied will result in `number`.

Also, if the number entered is `1`, you get two of the three possible outputs instead of just the first one. To fix this, put an `else` before the `if (flag == 1)`.

Comment: i edited my code but also the same wrong result where always print>> not prime

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
 
int number ;
char flag=0;
printf("please enter the number:");
scanf("%d",&number);

for(int i=1;i<number;i++)
{  
   if(number%i==0)
   {
     flag=1;
     break;
    }
}
if (number==1)
{ printf("%d neither prime nor not prime", number);}
else if ( flag==1 )
{ printf("%d is not prime",number);}
else
 { printf("%d is prime",number);}
  return 0;

}

Comment: My bad. It needs to be `for(int i=2;i<number;i++)`. It shouldn't check for the remainder of dividing by `1`.

Comment: OT:  please post code as part (or edit section) of your question rather than in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Just check reminder either it is 0 or 1, if you divide any number in the end it will give you either 0 or 1 in reminder.If reminder is 1 so number is prime or 0 number is not prime.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void) 
{

int number ;
char flag=0;
printf("please enter the number:");
scanf("%d",&number);


if((number>2)&&(number%2==0))
{
 flag=1;

}
if (number==1)
{ printf("%d neither prime nor not prime", number);}
if (flag==1)
{ printf("%d is not prime",number);}
else
 { printf("%d is prime",number);}
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: 15%2  != 0 but 15 not prime as 15%3=0   so i don't think this code will work successfully